# Find author of deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

There was a low-quality Stack Overflow question (along the lines of 'how do I ...' without showing effort). After several people pointed it out and getting close-votes, the author took the initiative to delete the question.

However, since I know a lot about the subject they asked about, I feel bad and want to help them off-site, however I now have no way of finding contact info.

Is there a way to retrieve the author details, given the (now deleted) question ID? The author was new and has 1 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really.  Unless the user has exposed contact details in their profile (Twitter/blog/etc.) then you can't contact them, and SE won't disclose PII to anyone.

All you can really do is try to engage the user in one of the chatrooms (assuming they can raise enough rep to do so), or ask >10K users if there's any contact details in their profile (as per Shadow's answer).  If not, you have to let this one go.

Or you can ask the question yourself (per the quality/scoping requirements of the site in question) and self-answer it.

Comment: The latter option, please. This is the whole spirit of Q&A: ask and answer once, so everyone can benefit in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Users with 10k rep can see the deleted question and give you link to the user's profile.

If you don't have 10k rep yourself, you can ask around in a chat room. Just don't push it.